# How to hide that your genetically modified character has turned almost immortal (but can still be killed)

Tags: biology, science-fiction, science-in-society

Now i am not going for a fantasy kind of feel, but more science fiction. So the character had undergone several harsh experiments and so lost the ability to physically feel pain and as a side effect her heart doesnt stop beating. She could "die" but not pass away,  if that makes any sense. No matter how much she loses blood or how fatally injured she gets, she is revived within seconds.
Her body doesnt regenerate immediatly but she still manages to stay alive.
So how do i make it so that she would explain all that without letting people know she'd been gentically modified? Especially after getting shot in the chest or getting her neck sliced open and getting up like it was nothing.

Comment: Okay well she doesnt want anyone to know she has been modified or how she is the way she is now. Especially since it has been done without her consent.

Comment: Soft Scifi possible. Hard Scifi, short of nanites not. Ignoring that, her explanation would be pointless and could actually cause more issues. The only real explanation are 1. She isn't human, 2. Religious explanation, 3. Super Science explanation.  None of those are really much better than genetic engineering. Honestly, I would just pretend it never happened. Unless it is on film or there are many witnesses, they cannot prove it.  It is too out there for the public to accept. Literally, if a video of this appeared on Youtube would you believe it?  The bullet missed, you are seeing things.

Comment: No what i meant was is if she was your friend for example and you were in a situation where one of your friends dies but then gets up normally. Of course you would ask questions. So how does she explain it if she didnt want to mention that she had been modified. She wants an explanation where it does not involve that she has been robbed of her humanity. For her sake and her friends and family.

Comment: I got that.  My point is that you cannot explain it while retaining her humanity. Any explanation is that she is no longer or was never human.  You either accept that she is not normal, or assume you saw wrong and are possibly crazy. Something like getting hit by a car you could explain she knew how to roll or was a good athlete and her instincts took over.  Something like getting shot or given a glasglow smile is impossible to explain.

Comment: @J.Roberts well honestly it's gonna be hard to explain that.  People don't normally just stand back up perfectly okay after a fatal blow.  Sure she could try to say that "it missed the vitals" but even still, you wouldn't just stand up normally and be okay.  An explanation will be needed and anything that would hide the fact would not be believable.  You can try to pass it off as some kind of religious Hand of God help but ya... she's gonna need to explain.

Comment: A really bad and convoluted explanation for getting shot, where noone sees the blood is that it hit a mcguffin or something in her pocket.  And then she shows the mcguffin with a bullet on it.  But either she carries it around or she has to run away afterwards and return with the mcguffin.

Comment: I was thinking that she would say she has Congenital insensitivity to pain (CIPA) and then pass it off that she didnt hit any vitals or she wasnt as seriously injured as she appeared to be. But CIPA is something you're born with so to a stranger that would be the perfect explanation but not to her parents and siblings.

Comment: Its going to be hard if she can't feel pain, people that can't feel pain hurt themselves a LOT but cause they don't realize they are, and I mean in strange ways like poor fitting shoes wearing the foot down to the bone, or tearing their flesh open on a sharp edge becasue they can't feel it tearing. She will start giving her self away in just day to day activities.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if her heart is blown up? Like to shreds?

Comment: Obviously by staying away from people who are likely to shoot her or cut her throat. That way there's less explaining to be done.

Comment: @John yeah well she already can't feel pain so she does hurt herself a lot although she takes a lot of precautions so as not to. This makes her life much harder. Of course she is going to give herself away little by little but at least it is from an illness ( that she claims to has) but not from genetic engineering (what had really happened)

Comment: @Dog she is not immortal, her heart just keeps beating even if her vitals were severely or fatally injured. Someone could cut off her arm but she wouldn't die of blood loss because her heart keeps beating (but slower as to not lose all her blood) but if there are situation from which she can revive from. For example, if her head was severed from her body that would surely kill her. So having her heart blow up to shreds would also kill her if there wasn't much to pump blood with.

Comment: Wait, how does your heart continuing to beat keep you from dying of blood loss? Do you mean it regenerates blood?

Comment: Well, first of all it slows down considerably and her blood starts generating blood at a very fast rate. I know it is not as realistic as it seems but i do have a very long explanation on how she got that way (genetic modification included) if you're interested.

Answer (score 2):

### Holographs

If technology in this world has developed realistic holographs capable of fooling the eye, then you could use them to fool your opponent (and your friends) as to whether you've even been injured.

Use holographs as a cover - literally - to conceal your injuries and carry on like nothing is wrong. By the time your healing factor had done its job, no one will be the wiser or even be able to prove that you were ever injured (except for the problem of blood or other fluids which would either need to also be concealed holographically or taken care of with some kind of medical implant/body suit.)

In fact, minor injuries wouldn't need to be concealed at all, only life-threatening ones that would raise questions.

In the heat of battle, it's pretty difficult to keep track of specific injuries as they happen, so when your character walks away from a fight with zero or only minor injuries they can shrug it off as luck or superior fighting ability.

Comment: An anchored holograph good enough to do that is really high tech.  There is also the issue with the whole blunt force trauma thing.  Getting shot is likely to land you on your ass.

Comment: Yes, also it is in a pretty modern setting and although higher technology and science is evolved she has no mean or desire to possess it. Also, there were several occurrences where she was stabbed or injured but only found out much later. I think maybe CIPA is my best choice but I was looking for something more believable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain this is possible to do. Any explanation she comes up with will inevitably only be able to convince a few people, usually strangers.

### Hologram

This has been discussed in another answer so I will be brief. Using a hologram may be able to cover up an injury. For example if she were sliced across the neck she could project a hologram of unharmed skin and say she dodged back or the knife was really blunt. This might work for injuries caused in the heat of battle or when people can't see her clearly but in most settings people will see the weapon pierce her skin and will see blood. They may also see her be thrown backwards by impact forces that should kill her in there own right.

### CIPA (Congenital Insensitivity to Pain with Anhidrosis)

This is a rare genetic disorder which prevents the sufferer feeling pain, heat and cold. It can let them seem to shrug of injuries but in reality they simply do not notice the injury due to lack of pain. This wouldn't help in your setting. CIPA might let the woman explain being able to walk away from a fight with a knife in her leg because she has no pain but people with CIPA heal just as slowly as people without (often slower because they don't realise they have the injury so end up aggravating it. Furthermore, it wouldn't allow her to survive fatal injuries such as bullets to the chest because CIPA doesn't give you healing powers. Finally it is a birth condition so friends and family will already know she does't have it.

### The weapon missed/bounced off my mcguffin

This would work if no one saw any evidence of the injury but shares all the problems of a hologram and basically would only work in a few, rare situations.

### Nanites, God save or Really good first aid

All of these work on the principle of her surviving because something intervened, either magic or advanced technology/first aid. These would be realistic as God could have healed her (assuming she is only trying to convince highly religious people) or the nano robots in her blood saved her (if the technology exists). The nanobots one is basically saying a technology saved her (nanobots) to cover up that a different technology (genetic engineering) saved her.

Comment: This answer adds nothing new.